# how to use xcodebuild to import a static lib into Xcode xcframework so that iOS app only calls xcframework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, xcodebuild

We have a propriety iOS static lib that contains Swift and C.  We want to put its executable into our framework project, to protect it.

We build static lib into the xcframework with xcodebuild at command line and then import framework project's .xcframework into our test app, but get build error "No such module 'M'".

xcodebuild script builds ok...

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme M -archivePath  build/M-iphoneos.xcarchive -sdk iphoneos SKIP_INSTALL=NO 

xcodebuild -create-xcframework  -library M/Release-iphoneos/libStatic_lib_Swift_C.a  -output  build/M.xcframework

rem  Copy framework executable into test app folder:
cp -R Build/M.xcframework         ../testApp/testApp
```

UPDATE...
We changed "-framework ..." to "-library M/Release-iphoneos/libStatic_lib_Swift_C.a" but app still gets build error: "No such module 'M'"
Frameworks's Build Settings Search Path & Import Path = static lib path.
App's Build Settings search path & import path = M.xcframework path.

Note: there are no imported .h files. Only access to static lib is a single public Swift func for app. Internally, the func calls a bunch of C then returns inout args back to calling app.

Comment: UPDATE:  We change -framework to -library but get build error: "No such module 'M'" even though we verified Build Settings > search path and import path set to: M/M.scframework

Answer (score 1):

Putting a static lib into a framework in no way "keeps it more private." I assume you just mean that you want to ship a binary xcframework. That's fine.

To your question, you're passing `-framework`, which requires that the output be a framework already. But you have a static lib. You want to pass the `-library` and `-headers` options to bundle that into an xcframework. (Note that an xcframework is not the same thing as a framework.)

Also make sure that you've read [Creating a multiplatform binary framework bundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle/), and particularly the section on build settings. You're passing SKIP_INSTALL=NO, but you may not have set BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION as required in the docs.

Comment: We changed -framework to -library but get build error: "No such module 'M'" even though we verified Build Settings > search path and import path set to: M/M.xcframework   Note: there are no .h files. Only a single public Swift func for app. Internally, there's a bunch of C that this Swift calls then returns inout args back to calling app.

Comment: I can definitely picture the problem you're having, but I don't know how to walk you through this in SO format without having access to the exact xcodeproj, in which case, it would likely spiral well past what make sense for an SO answer. It's possible that someone will post a very on-point answer here, but this feels like a consulting problem (see profile if you're interested in that).

Comment: Hi, Rob.  That might be a solution for us.  What's your rate?

Comment: You can contact me at rob@neverwood.org with some details of your project, and I'd be happy to discuss.

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  My colleague Amruth will now contact you re consulting, to help us move forward.